# Add image to excel worksheet using Interop and Iron Python

Tags: excel, image, export, interop, ironpython

What is the best way to add images to an excel workbook using Iron Python and Interop only?  I can't use any custom excel packages. I can get this method below using Shapes to work but its limited in image size to 100.

`ws.Shapes.AddPicture(myimage, False, True, 415, 1, 100,100)`

Can't seem to find any other Ironpy methods that work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to go back in time for this one big thanks to Konrad_K_Sobon
This is using Interop only, so it works in Iron Python without any addons like xlpy.

```
myimage = os.path.join(userdirectory,'file.png')
img = worksheet2.Pictures().Insert(myimage)
range = img.ShapeRange
range.LockAspectRatio = True
range.Width = 300
range.Height = 400 
img.Left = worksheet2.Cells[5,6].Left
img.Top = worksheet2.Cells[5,6].Top
img.Placement = 1
img.PrintObject = True
```